# How to find my Barbarian King Level on my Clash of Clans account?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Have can I find out my "Barbarian King Level" and "Archer Queen Level" on my account? Where does it show their level?

Answer (score 4):

You can see your Barbarian King and Archer Queen walking around. It shows their HP and their level next to their head.

Otherwise click on their platform and click the "Info" button. It will say their level on the info screen.

Comment: yeah. this should be marked as the answer @Moh

Comment: You can also see the level of both, along with the level of all of your troops and spells, in your profile. Arguably, that's the easiest way to find out since you don't have to go searching through your base to locate your BK or AQ.